# Does "precluded from" require a direct object?

Tags: verbs, objects

In a copy-editing job I'm doing, I came across the following phrase:

"a man is precluded from all women except for his wife"

- i.e., his sexual relationship with her is (should be, anyway) exclusive.

This doesn't really seem correct to me, since I'd think that "preclude" requires a direct object, like "precluded from marriage with" or something like that. Am I correct, or is this sentence fine as is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in believing that *preclude* requires a direct object. However, the example sentence is still correct, because here *preclude* has been put into the passive voice. You wrote:

> A man is precluded from all women except his wife.

This is equivalent to:

> [Society] precludes a man from all women except his wife.

In this example it's quite clear that the object of *preclude* is *a man*, as expected. In the first example the direct object has been made the subject, as normal for passive constructions.

What *is* unusual about the first sentence is the fact that *from* is taking an ordinary noun as its object, while the normal idiom requires that the object of *from* be a verbal noun of some sort. So either of the following variants would be preferable:

> A man is precluded from sleeping with all women except his wife. (Using the participle *sleeping*.)
>
> A man is precluded from copulation with all women except his wife. (Using the abstract noun *copulation*.)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in saying that 'preclude' needs a direct object. The definition of preclude is 'to rule out or eliminate' something; saying 'A man is ruled out from all women except for his wife' makes little sense.

Comment: As JSBangs has said, the question isn't about the direct object of 'preclude', but about what kind of word can go in its *indirect* object slot.